Uses of Feedthrough Capacitors on PMIC
I am currently designing a PCB which will use the Texas Instruments LP876242-Q1. The board is a similar board to their TIDA-020047 reference design, so I am studying their design decisions. One confusing part is their use of feedthrough capacitors for the input capacitance to their buck converter. More specifically, their recommendations for input capacitance says:
"For optimal performance, additional 1 μF 3-terminal input capacitors are required. Buck1 and buck2 can share one 3-T capacitor and buck3 and buck4 can share one 3-T capacitor." From LP876242-Q1 page 276.
At least for me, I took this as the input current would flow "through" the feedthrough section, to provide the benefit of filtering. However, they have used them is where each of the feedthrough pads is connected to a separate VIN supply. The schematic below explains the layout better:

C89 and C77 are the 3-Terminal Capacitors. From the BOM, these are Murata NFM18HC105C1C3D. The PCB shows the connection more intuitively, notice C89's middle pin being ground, and the outsides being PVIN_B1 and PVIN_B2:

My question really relates to whether there is any benefit to using these feedthrough capacitors over 2 "normal" decoupling capacitors. The layout is clearly made easier on this specific IC, as the pinout goes 12-PVIN_B1, 13-PGND, 14-PVIN_B2, so fitting multiple caps would always compromise one or the other supply. I have never used the 3-Terminal caps, should I take this as a normal practice for these multiple power input buck converters?


C89 and C77 are the 3-Terminal Capacitors. From the BOM, these are
Murata NFM18HC105C1C3D.

If you look at the data for this device on the Murata site, you'll see that it provides significant attenuation from input to output (aka S21) from 1 MHz to over 1 GHz: -

I'm not saying your circuit needs it of course; that was down to the designer's thoughts but, if there is a lot of power supply noise in this broad area then some benefit may be obtained.

should I take this as a normal practice for these multiple power input buck converters?

No, not normal practice.

I agree, that is how I thought they were being used, with the high frequency component of the power input being attenuated at the output side of the capacitor. However, if the capacitor's input and output pin are both connected to the same power input, is this attenuation actually doing anything?

It looks like it's connected but, it still acts like an inductor and that's what causes the resonance at around 20 MHz.

I think I understand, the converter switches at 8.8Mhz, so close to that 20MHz resonant frequency, for a lot of attenuation. For anyone else interested, I found this resource on TDK's website: https://product.tdk.com/en/techlibrary/solutionguide/3tf03.html
